# Is it possible to programmatically add an iPhone contact to the phone favorites?

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, addressbook

I have an iPhone application that adds new contacts via the Address Book Framework.

Is it possible to programmatically add a new or existing contact to the phone "Favorites" list?

If it is possible, pointer to doc, code or API please?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't believe it is possible using documented methods (so no App Store for you if you work it out). It is not a feature of the Address Book API but part of Apple's own Contacts application.