# How to make contact favorite in Address book of iPhone

Tags: iphone, ios, abaddressbook

I want to add a contact in Address Book of iPhone programmatically and want to make it favorite such that it will be display in favorite list of native contact app. Also can an already existing number be added to favorite list programmatically?

Comment: might help. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1598716/is-it-possible-to-programmatically-add-an-iphone-contact-to-the-phone-favorites

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That is not available to developers, as I found out the hard way